# Is it possible to setup a system based on Arduino Due running QNX?

Tags: arduino-due

I would like to create some QNX applications and test them in a hardware different than my virtual machine. Since Arduino Due board is based on the Atmel SAM3X8E ARM Cortex-M3 CPU and QNX® Neutrino® RTOS supports that processor, I was wondering if it is possible make them work together.

What would be the challenges to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

> Since Arduino Due board is based on the Atmel SAM3X8E ARM Cortex-M3 CPU and QNX® Neutrino® RTOS supports that processor, I was wondering if it is possible make them work together.

Does QNX really support ARM Cortex-M3? I believe that is not possible as the processor does not have the necessary hardware support.

[image: QNX Neutrino RTOS Architectuer]

Please see the [BSP](http://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.bsp/wiki/BSPAndDrivers) list.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Typically the challenge in porting a new OS to a board is to configure stuff like:

- system clock (to drive the scheduler of the OS at the right frequence)
- board specific I/O
- components that are not part of the SoC (but iirc DUE doesn't have any of these)
- individual HW blocks (like on which serial port redirect the character interface, if your application has any)
- wakeup sources, in case you have/want low power modes and you need the board to wake up when something specific happens

None of these are impossible tasks and they are all good to learn more about the system, but otoh it's unlikely you can rush through them.

The good news is that probably you will not need them all and not immediately.

But some you will have to perform and they will require understanding how your OS works and having the technical reference manual of your board and SoC.

Comment: I guess you are talking in general as QNX is not directly open-source??